# Cerrar actividades Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una app con un menú lateral.
La duda la tengo que cada vez que uso una de las opciones del menú me abre una ventana nueva.

```
  } else if (id == R.id.cine) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplication(), Cine.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        finish();
```

Hasta aquí bien, pero la duda la tengo que he puesto el finish para cerrar la ventana anterior.

Pero no me gusta como queda ya que me gustaría poder retroceder a la anterior dándole atrás sin que estuviera cerrada. Pero si quito el finish entonces me abre ventanas y son como muchas aplicaciones abiertas.

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo ?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, tenes razon no esta bueno que se apilen muchos activities sin criterio. Si tenes un menu lateral lo mejor opcion es usar fragments. Te cuento como yo lo haria: Pongo un activity Main con un fragment container, hago que cada opcion del menu lateral sea un fragment que se va remplazando. Sobreescribo el boton de back para que siempre me lleve al fragment principal. Y luego si hace falta que cada fragment abra un activity. De esta forma los activities que se apilan tienen un sentido.

Comment: la idea era hacerlo con actividades. Si es con Fragments puedo hacerlo. Pero no se si se puede hacer con actividades y es algo que me gustaría saber xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es el requerimiento es usar actividades, en realidad solo abre la Activity (no es necesario usar `startActivityForResul()`), para permitir solo una instancia de la Activity  define para cada Activity dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml, la propiedad:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

la Actividad principal no la finalices, con esto al regresar, tu Actividad principal permanecerá abierta.

```
 } else if (id == R.id.cine) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplication(), Cine.class);
        startActivity(intent);   
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        //finish();
  }
```